# Is it bad to pass class object between methods?

Tags: java, oop

Is it bad to pass instances of objects between methods in a class? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
public void game() {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
}

public void changeCard(Deck deck) {
    deck.replaceCard(deck);
}
```

Comment: i do it myself, i don`t think its bad. other method would be member variables

Comment: I'd say this is one of the features which makes this kind of programming to object oriented programming

Comment: What could be considered bad in your example is that the method modifies its parameter. This could be considered a side-effect, too much of this will make your code difficult to understand.

Comment: There's no reason why passing objects from one method by another, in general, would be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... passing class object would be quite difficult in [java](/questions/tagged/java). On the other hand the in-build mechanism of passing value of the reference is very useful and we all do that daily.

[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/4723795)

Operating with objects is a main principle of `Object Oriented Programming` and Java is object oriented.

Remember that you don't pass the whole object. You can imagine that as passing the instructions on how to find that object in memory.

Comment: @Danielh112 just in case you want to ask more questions in the future, I strongly recommend reading [ask] and [mcve]. These are interesting articles about how to write not to get downvoted.